# screencasting in android using HDMI wifi dongle

Tags: android, wifi-direct, mirroring

I have been searching a lot for implementing screen cast(miracast) in android and got more confused. I have a HDMI wifi dongle. Now as i plug the dongle and open my app need to search for available devices and as user selects devices the mirroring should start and my screen need to reflect to the device which has plug the device. For now From settings we need to go to display and turn wireless display on and connect to them. As of now i tryed to do this by `WifiP2pManager` class and got a list of device and connected to my device. But it is not showing as connected on settings wireless display which need to be connected for screen casting. Now my question is can i start that casting from my app and how ?

Comment: What is "a HDMI wifi dongle"? If this is something that you are plugging into the device, it is unlikely to be integrated with Android's display system. Miracast would involve perhaps talking to a "dongle" that plugs into the TV or monitor, but Miracast has nothing to do with `WifiP2pManager`.

Comment: @CommonsWare this is a HDMI Wireless Wi-Fi Dongle which can be plug in to tv. I need to have have a button that simply starts miracast(mirroring)

Comment: @CommonsWare i founf this document which says we need to connect to WiFi-direct before mirroring.[link](http://support.actiontec.com/doc_files/ScreenBeam%20with%20Nexus%204%20User%20Guide.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

there is no public API that allows you to manipulate directly the connection, but you can integrate an action that should do what you want, through the [MediaRouteActionProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/MediaRouteActionProvider.html)

[image: MediaRoute Button]

Using this, you can display a button inside your action bar. When the user will click on it, it will show the list of paired devices and do a quick scan. From there, the user will be able to directly initiate the connection to an available device.

It's working on most devices, simply not returning the action on those that don't have any paired devices or don't support Miracast (+some Samsung's that don't use the MediaRoute system for Miracast connection).

Comment: can you detail more on those Samsungs not using the MediaRoute system ?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to have have a button that simply starts miracast(mirroring)

That's not possible through the Android SDK, sorry. Whether there is a way for an app running with superuser privileges on a rooted device to do it, I cannot say.